# sql - Oracle table create error ORA-00904 invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

My code is giving an "ORA-00904 invalid identifier" error.  What might be the cause?

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
s_ID int,
S_NAMe varchar2(10),
S_major varchar2(20),
CONSTRAINT PK_s_ID PRIMARY KEY (s_ID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_D_ID FOREIGN KEY (D_ID) REFERENCES dep (D_ID)
);
```

Comment: Maybe `constraint FK_D_ID foreign key (D_ID)` should be `constraint FK_D_ID foreign key (s_ID)`?, Certainly you have no D_ID column in this table...

Answer (score 0):

Your last constraint, `D_ID` references a column that doesn't exist. You need to add it and it's definition to your column list. Also, `int` is not a valid data type for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, i appreciate your help , i forget to write the foreign key as a column on student table and i think int is valid on my oracle 11g the table already created  , here is code it worked with me

create table student (
s_ID int ,
S_NAMe varchar2 (10),
S_major varchar2(20),
D_ID number (10) ,
Constraint PK_s_ID primary key (s_ID), 
constraint FK_D_ID foreign key (D_ID) references dep (D_ID) );